# Doctrine query : confusing addWhere, andWhere, orWhere

Tags: sql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a query :

```
$q->andWhere($q->getRootAlias().'.is_published = ?', 1);
$q->andWhere($q->getRootAlias().'.published_at >= ?', time());
$q->leftJoin($q->getRootAlias().'.EventLdapGroup l');
$q->andWhereIn('l.ldap_group_id', $permissions_id );
$q->orWhere('l.ldap_group_id IS NULL);
```

which outputs :

```
FROM 
    Event r LEFT JOIN r.EventLdapGroup l 
WHERE 
    r.is_published = ? AND 
    r.published_at >= ? AND 
    l.ldap_group_id IN (?, ?) OR 
    l.ldap_group_id IS NULL
```

The only problem is that if `ldap_group_id` is null (the last condition) it'll remove the `is_published` and `published_at` conditions.

I want something like that [either the values are in ldap_group_id, or either it's null] :

```
FROM 
    Event r LEFT JOIN r.EventLdapGroup l 
WHERE 
    r.is_published = ? AND 
    r.published_at >= ? AND 
    (l.ldap_group_id IN (?, ?) OR l.ldap_group_id IS NULL)
```

And i must say that i'm lost with the complex where condition.
How to achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok solution is here :

```
$q->andWhere('(l.ldap_group_id IN ( ' . implode(",", $permissions_id) . ') OR l.ldap_group_id IS NULL )' );
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of your last two lines

```
$q->andWhereIn('l.ldap_group_id', $permissions_id );
$q->orWhere('l.ldap_group_id IS NULL);
```

Try this approach

```
$q->andWhere($qb->expr()->orx(
   $qb->expr()->in( 'l.ldap_group_id', $permissions_id ),
   $qb->expr()->isNull( 'l.ldap_group_id' );
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the query builder isn't available in Doctrine 1.2 :'(. Found the solution (see below)